# Update a Silverlight application while clients are running it

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am new to Silverlight and web development and I was wondering if there was a way to update a  Silverlight application while clients are running it. For example, suppose you can have many clients running the app. 24/7 and you want to do an update, how can you do it without losing compatibility with the clients currently running it? I know that if I stop, recompile and start the server, clients only have to do F5 and they will get the latest version, but that is not desirable if they are in the middle of processing something important.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: I question if Silverlight is the right choice for an app that must _never_ close.

Comment: @David Could you provide me with technologies that are more appropriate for this scenario?

Comment: Do you mean that __a__ client may be running the app 24/7 or that your application as a service may be used by many clients such that your application is in use somewhere at all times? Some answer and comments here would seem to think you meant the former others the latter, it would help if you clarified

Comment: It is possible but unlikely that a client runs the app 24/7 (not actively using it 24/7 but leaving it open all the time and really using it some times). It's more likely that many clients run the application such that it is in use somewhere at all times. If I can support the first, that's great, but if not I'll try to at least support the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually can work. You can dynamically load a xap file. Just structure your app in such a way that you can update and deploy parts of the application. You'll need to build an updater service that will watch for changes and prompt the user to update a specific component.

Check out this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/MEFDynamicLoading.aspx) on dynamic loading of xap.

Comment: Interesting! I'd really like to see how much overhead it introduces.

Comment: Well that's pretty nice and seems like exactly what I need. I'll try that thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you make sure that your WCF service has backwards compatibility (all calls from old clients are valid) its not a problem to have outdated clients accessing it. After all, once they download the XAP, they no longer rely on it not changing on the server, just like any standalone client on a remote machine.

Comment: That's also what I thought at first, but is there a way to update the server with no "down time"? If a client is doing some action while I update the server, the server will be down and so his action will fail. It might be impossible to have a server that's never down, but I wanted to know SO's opinion about that before going for an option where the server must be down some times.

Comment: WCF services used by SL are stateless by design. Your SL app can  manage the situation where a WCF call fails and retry the operation (perhaps for as long as it might take to restart the server). It's not given out of the box but i don't see why it would be hard to implement.

Comment: Versioning your webservices and rolling updates using multiple servers is the way most companies handle these kind of situations.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to remember is that although some parts are spaced out, the application is pretty much contained in a xap file. To edit that is to edit the entire project. So essentially you'd have a situation where you are editing the xap (that is currently on the user's system) and running it at the same time.

Even if you could manage it, you'd have to have a system to check and make sure the parts you are updating are not being used at the time while the program is running.

While I am no Silverlight expert, this situation seems like a Cluster F, which I pretty much doubt is possible at all.

Also when is the last time you saw any product that updated while it was working? Or if it does, never had to restart?

Comment: Actually I pretty much agree with you, but I just talked with my boss and a more senior developer and they both seemed to think that Silverlight probably offers a better update mechanism than just refresh/restart the application, so I wanted to know whether or not there existed one.

Comment: Are you asking about updating the client side application or the server side part? If it was the server side part, then it may be possible, but the time it takes to change to the new one would cause problems, and if there is any temporary tokens, they would need to be maintained with the new one. I know even less about server side stuff so idk.

Comment: I'm asking about the server side and the client side. The server side will change (i.e. the WCF services) but can be kept backwards-compatible, and the client side will change also (like Shawn proposed, I can update only some parts of the client side so that they can be updated without restarting the app)

Answer (score 1):

Having developed several Silverlight applications I can tell you that this is not something that you would want to do. You have to remember that Silverlight applications are downloaded to the client machine and then run from there. In theory, if you push an update which only impacts the client side, then all existing users should still be able to continue using the old version of the application until they refresh their browser. This way users will be forced to refresh to get changes but they won't lose current functionality.

However, if you made changes to the web services which silverlight calls and pushed those changes, then it's entirely possible that the current user's version of the application will no longer be able to access those services and therefore crash or keep throwing errors.

Just to add something - If you're planning an update which will impact the users, it's better to do the update in batches and warn users of a possible down-time. (If possible)